# Does Jordan outer measure satisfiy finite subadditivity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Dose Jordan outer measure $$m^{*,(J)}(E):= \inf_{B \supset E, B\space\text{elementary}}m(B)$$ have the property:$$m^{*,(J)}(E \cup F) \leq m^{*,(J)}(E) + m^{*,(J)}(F)$$ where an elementary set is a finite union of boxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that if $S,T$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$ bounded from below, then $\inf S+\inf T=\inf(S+T)$, where $S+T=\{s+t:s\in S,t\in T\}$. Therefore the right-hand side of your inequality is equal to

$$\inf D,\ \text{where}\ D=\{m(B)+m(B'): B\supseteq E, B'\supseteq F;\ B, B'\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{elementary}}\}\,;$$

since $m(B)+m(B')\geq m(B\cup B')$, and $B\cup B'$ is an elementary set containing $E\cup F$, it follows that $m(B)+m(B')\geq m(B\cup B')\geq m^{*,(J)}(E \cup F)$, so the number $m^{*,(J)}(E \cup F)$ is a lower bound for the set $D$, and consequently $m^{*,(J)}(E \cup F)\leq\inf D$, as desired.